# How to read multi index dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is my dataframe which called df

```
University  Subject  Colour
Melb        Math     Red
            English  Blue
Sydney      Math     Green
            Arts     Yellow
            English  Green
Ottawa      Med      Blue
            Math     Yellow
```

Both University and Subject are the index key for this dataframe

when I do this

```
print(df.to_dict('index'))
```

I get

```
{(Melb, Math): {'Colour': Red}, (Melb, English): {'Colour': Blue}, ...
```

When I do this

```
print(df["Colour"])
```

I get this

```
University  Subject  Colour
Melb        Math     Red
            English  Blue
Sydney      Math     Green
            Arts     Yellow
            English  Green
Ottawa      Med      Blue
            Math     Yellow
```

When I do

```
print(df["University"])
```

I get an error

```
KeyError: 'University'
```

What I want is a way to read each value separately

I want to read the University and another read for Subject and a third for the Colour

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quicker way to do this is by using python's **zip** function, this method will be **significantly faster** than manually running a for loop.

#### Quick-Answer to your question:

```py
university_list = list(zip(*df.index))[0]
subject_list = list(zip(*df.index))[1]
colour_list = list(df['Colour'])
```

### Explaination

#### To get Indexes as List:

```py
index_list = list(zip(*df.index))
```

**Output:**

`[('Melb','Sydney','Ottawa'),('Math','English','Math','Arts',...)]`

You will get **a list of tuples** where each tuples will be relating to an **index column**.

*(columns will be in **Left to Right** **order**: such as **1st index-column** will be the **first tuple**, **2nd index-column** will be the **second tuple** and so on!)*

Now, to get the **Separate Index Column Lists** you can simply do,

```py
Universities = list(index_list[0]) #this will give you separate list for university ('Melb','Sydney','Ottawa')
Subjects = list(index_list[1]) #this will give you separate list for Subjects ('Math','English','Math','Arts',...)
```

#### Getting data as a list from Non-Index Columns

You can do this by simply doing,

```py
column_data = list(df['column_name'])

#which in your case will be

colour_list = list(df['Colour'])
```

#### **I am extending the answer to answer one of the comments.**

Now, Imagine a case where you need the **whole Dataframe as a list of Tuples** where each tuple will have data of a column. (Index columns included)

The list will look something like,

`[(Col-1_data, ,...),(Col-2_data, ,...),...]`

To achieve something like this you will have to **reset the indexes**, **Fetch the data** and **set indexes again**. Below code will do the task,

```py
index_names = list(df.index.names) #saving current indexes so that we can reassign them later.
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
dataframe_raw_list = df.values.tolist() #This will be a list of tuples where each tuple is a row of dataframe
df.set_index(index_names, inplace = True)

dataframe_columns_list = list(zip(*dataframe_raw_list)) #This will be a list of tuples where each tuple is a Column of dataframe
```

**Output**:

`[(Col-1_data, ,...),(Col-2_data, ,...),...]`

Comment: is there a way i can list the 3 columns together in one string something like (Melb,Math,Red),(Melb,English,Blue),(Sydney,Meth,Yellow)

Comment: @asmgx **Yes there is**. Unfortunately there is no straight way because pandas doesn't treat the **Index columns** as a **Data Column**. So to achieve this you have to first **Reset the indexes**, **Fetch the Data** and then **Set indexes again.** I have edited my answer, see the last section for your answer.

Comment: what is "dataframe_list"

Comment: sorry its a typo from my side, its **dataframe_raw_list**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first level of your index ('University') with this:

```
[i[0] for i in df.index]
```

Similarly for the second level ('Subject')

```
[i[1] for i in df.index]
```

Also, if you want to just get the values of 'Colour' column, you can do it with:

```
list(df['Colour'])
```

Comment: is there a way i can list the 3 columns together in one string something like (Melb,Math,Red),(Melb,English,Blue),(Sydney,Meth,Yellow)